# How can you know which mySQL code to use in which program?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I'm working on mySQL and have installed WAMP-server and mySQL workbench.

I know mySQL is a standard, but with various dialects. My question is, how can I know when to use which code?

Sometimes when creating a table, you have to write test and sometimes 'test'.

Some examples:

1. `CREATE TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, no INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(no);`
2. `CREATE TABLE 'test'('id' NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 'name' VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 'no' INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(no));`
3. `CREATE TABLE test(id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, no INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id), FOREIGN KEY(no) REFERENCES Persons(no));`

Some places you need to end the command with ; and some places not...
Same with ' .
And some places you write the PRIMARY KEY at the back of the decleration and some places you enter it at the end.

WAMP server DOS, WAMP server phpmyadmin and mySQL workbench is all different.

THanks in advance for the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

For table and columns names use backticks `tableName`,but they are necessary only when using reserved names.[Reserved names in Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

Quotes are used for strings '123'-this is a string

Semicolon indicates that the statement ends,so it is necessary when you have multiple statements.
Primary key you can add it on the column definition,or add it later.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize that it was different with backticks and quotes. It's hard to see the differences in my book. So to sum up what you're saying. I only need the backticks when if I want to call a variable i.e. GENERAL, then it should be ` general `? And I can use them all the time if I want?

Comment: @user2963949 again backticks are for column and tables names.I don't know what you call a variable.IN your example test,id,name and no.Yes you can use them all the time and yes general is a reserved word and if you want to name a table general you need backticks.